# Why are these two questions not closed as exact duplicates (and merged)?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

This question was asked on Code Review:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/19022/3973

This question was migrated to Code Review (by me, from Stack Overflow), which is an exact duplicate (word-for-word) from the same poster:

[Tree node filtering with List<TreeNode>](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/19023/3973)

Given that they are *exactly* the same, I'd expect the following:

- The version that I migrated be closed as off-topic as well (if the other one is truly off-topic)
- The one that is closed as off-topic really be closed as an exact duplicate of the one migrated from Stack Overflow, and that version deleted (it's a duplicate, but having an exact word-for-word duplicate is noise and doesn't help with searchability here).

But, that's currently not the case.

My preference is for the second action, but there might be something missing here.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I did that, but I don't recall it.

I've changed the closed reason and merged the questions.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you.